# Does breaking up a Chrome extension into many files make it slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension with thousands of lines of JavaScript. Putting them all into one file would be insanity, especially since it's vanilla JS and therefore not very structured or modular.

Breaking it up into multiple scripts sounds like a sane solution, but in my case speed is absolutely critical. Would I see a noticeable performance drop if I split my single JavaScript file into a dozen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt any difference would be noticeable. On websites, however, you'll normally develop using multiple files and then have a build process that concatenates and compresses all your JavaScript files into one, reducing HTTP requests. The same technique can be applied to Chrome extensions if you're concerned about it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Do you know of a good program/website that can minify and concatenate multiple files in a certain order?

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler: If you're on a UNIX-like system, you can use `cat` to concatenate files. As for compression, there are several options, including UglifyJS, Google Closure Compiler, and YUI Compressor. Tools like Make can tie all the tools together.